# Definition for rule 'react/require-extension' was not found

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, eslint

I have started to use Atom to work react-native.When I open index.js from Atom.I am getting error such as "definition for rule 'react/require-extension' was not found"  top of the code line.I think ,ıt couldn't import @format .

I don't know exactly. I am newbie at react.Any experience about this trouble or any advise ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6YZR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9gpL.png)

Comment: Please paste your code directly into your question instead of providing it as images.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `eslint` for your ReactNative project then edit your `.eslintrc` file and add this snip of code

> "rules": {
>       "react/require-extension": "off"   }

Now `.eslintrc` file should look like this.

```
{
  "extends": "rallycoding",
  "rules": {
    "react/require-extension": "off"
  }
}
```

[image]