# Definition for rule 'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps' was not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, standardjs

I am getting the following eslint error after adding `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` in my code.

> 8:14  error  Definition for rule 'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps' was not found

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55383611/definition-for-rule-react-require-extension-was-not-found) post to fix this but the solution mentioned doesn't work in my case. Any clue how to suppress this *eslint* error?

PS I'm using [standardjs](https://standardjs.com/) in conjuction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not a perfect** solution but changing:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

to:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

suppressed that error.

Comment: I advise against using `// eslint-disable-next-line` as that will completely disable all ESLint rules for the following line.

Comment: Agree, disables should always be as specific as possible to only the rule(s) that really need to be disabled.  This should not be considered a solution.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. This is a really bad recommendation, especially for this lint issue.

Comment: `// eslint-disable-next-line` shouldn't be used to disable as it would disable catching any other rule voilations

Answer (score 119):

This typically happens because the `react-hooks` plugin is missing in the `.eslintrc` plugin configuration. Ensure you have added `react-hooks` as in the example below:

```
"plugins": ["react", "react-hooks",],
```

Comment: This should really be considered the accepted answer.

Comment: if I don't have a .eslintrc I can just crate a .eslintrc file and add "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks",] in it ? Which directory should I put it in?

Comment: [https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) gives you almost all the information you need to know about the configurations

Comment: Which file does this go in?

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you define your react-hooks both in extends and plugins array like this

```
"extends": [
    "react-hooks",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "react-hooks"
  ],
```

Comment: This created an error for me: `Failed to load plugin 'react-hook' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react-hook'`

Comment: This is incorrect. Do NOT extend. Follow the official guide: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: the official guide is useful

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have put the rule in the `rules` object in your `.eslintrc`. Installing the plugin alone is not enough for the rules to start working

```
"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
```

and I assume you have already added `react-hooks` plugin into the `plugins` array in the `.eslintrc`

Comment: Will `"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off"` or `"react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0` work to disable globally ?

Comment: Hey, Taylor, yes both "off" and 0 should work to disable the rule. It depends on what you refer to as "global" in this case. If the eslint config is in your application folder then it will turn it off for the application workspace, if it is a global config and used in many projects it will disable it globally

Answer (score 3):

Put below code to package.json

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this worked for me create-react-app version 5.0.1 react 17

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using **vscode** and you have in your package.json the necessary packages such as

`"eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",`

and in your `eslintrc.js`

what the other answers have suggested then you might have to just **restart**

`ESLint: Restart ESLint Server` from

`cmd/ctrl + shift + P`