# useCallBack react-hooks/exhaustive-deps warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

This is part of my code in React js:

```
export default function Registration() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
    const [password, setPassword] = useState(null);
    const [passwordRepeat, setPasswordRepeat] = useState(null);
    const [isFieldsOK, setFieldsOK] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (checkFieldsOK()) {
            setFieldsOK(true);
        } else {
            setFieldsOK(false);
        }
    }, [checkFieldsOK])

    const checkFieldsOK = () => {
        return (isEmail(email) && isValidPassword(password) && passwordRepeat === password);
    }
}
```

I have the isFieldsOK state which tells me if my fields are valid, and I want it to "listen" to every change in the Registration function. After running this, I get this warning:

```
The 'checkFieldsOK' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 34) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the definition of 'checkFieldsOK' in its own useCallback() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

What exactly wrong with my code? What should I change and why?
Thank you!

Comment: If you are using eslint checkout this link. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59611822/definition-for-rule-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps-was-not-found

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I would consider moving `checkFieldsOK` expression above the `useEffect`.

Then ask yourself, when `checkFieldsOK` is created, called?

Assuming `isEmail` and `isValidPassword` are functions declared outside of your component, to fix the linter issue you need to either wrap the `checkFieldsOK` with a `useCallback`:

```
const checkFieldsOK = useCallback(() => {
        return (
          isEmail(email) &&
          isValidPassword(password) &&
          passwordRepeat === password
        );
    }, [email, password, passwordRepeat])
```

This way the `checkFieldsOK` will update it's inputs whenever the `email`, `password` or `passwordRepeat` would change.

or move the `checkFieldsOK` into the useEffect and update the effect dependencies:

```
    useEffect(() => {

      const checkFieldsOK = () => {
        return (
          isEmail(email) && 
          isValidPassword(password) && 
          passwordRepeat === password
         );
    }
        if (checkFieldsOK()) {
            setFieldsOK(true);
        } else {
            setFieldsOK(false);
        }
    }, [email, password, passwordRepeat])
```

This way your effect will be triggered only when email, password or passwordRepeat state changes.

You could simplify further into:

```
    useEffect(() => {

      const fieldsOK = 
          isEmail(email) && 
          isValidPassword(password) && 
          passwordRepeat === password
        
       setFieldsOK(fieldsOK);

    }, [email, password, passwordRepeat])
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't wrap `checkFieldsOK` in `useCallback` it's not memoized, which means it gets recreated on every render. And because your `useEffect` has `checkFieldsOK` as a dependency, that effect will also run every render.

Exactly as the error message says, first (and I believe incorrect) option is to move the function declaration inside the `useEffect` like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const checkFieldsOK = () => {
        return (isEmail(email) && isValidPassword(password) && passwordRepeat === password);
    }

    if (checkFieldsOK()) {
        setFieldsOK(true);
    } else {
        setFieldsOK(false);
    }
}, []);
```

But this means it will only run on mount (since the dependency array is empty), so a better approach is to wrap the `checkFieldsOK` function in a `useCallback` so it isn't remade every re-render and the effect only gets run when the field values change:

```
const checkFieldsOK = useCallback(() => {
    return (isEmail(email) && isValidPassword(password) && passwordRepeat === password);
}, [email, password, passwordRepeat]);
```

In the second `useCallback` approach, it behaves like so:

1. Field value changes
2. `checkFieldsOK` function gets remade
3. `useEffect` gets run and checks validation of the fields, updating state as needed